# Recursively create new promises

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to get the Promise.all function to work with a recursively structure.

The function that's been called from the for loop can create promises as well, but somehow the `Promise.all` function seems to be finished before the work has finished, and I don't have a clue why.

```
this.promised = [];
parseItem( relation ) {

    if( relation.wasResolved === true ) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {

        console.log( 'Parsing ' + relation.displaytitle );

        let result = await this.MediaWiki.ask('[[Has source element::'+ relation.fulltext +']]|?Has target element');

        // Loop over the API results
        for( let k in result ) {

            let targetElements = result[k].printouts['Has target element'];

            // Loop over every target element
            for( let index in targetElements) {

                let itemIndex = this.getIndex( targetElements[index] );

                // Only resolve known elements
                if( itemIndex !== -1 ) {
                    // Set parent && resolve childs
                    this.elementsInView[itemIndex].parent = relation;
                    // Resolve
                    this.promised.push( this.parseItem( this.elementsInView[itemIndex] ) );
                }
            }
        }

        // Set wasResolved to true
        relation.wasResolved = true;

        resolve(true);
    });
}

update() {

    // Loop over every element in the view
    for( let index in this.elementsInView ) {
        let element = this.elementsInView[index];
        // If the viewItem has a assigned hostId, add it to the queue
        if( element.host !== -1 ) {
            this.promised.push( this.parseItem( element ) );
        }
    }

    Promise.all(this.promised).then(value =>{
        this.finalize();
    });

}

finalize() {
    for( let index in this.elementsInView ) {
        let element = this.elementsInView[index];
        if( element.wasResolved === true ) {
            console.log( element );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the question remains the same

Comment: I would primarily guess that the issue is, when you call `Promise.all` the value of `this.promised` is used but it's not complete. Let's say there's one item in there, and then as part of the promise completing, it adds 20 items to `this.promised`. Well those values weren't in `this.promised` when you passed it to `Promise.all` so it didn't end up waiting for them. It would be better if you built up a single promise inside `parseItem` that, when complete represents all created promises from that call being complete.

Comment: Yes, whilst you haven't changed the question, the answer has changed. The mistake you had in there earlier would definitely have caused problems!

Comment: You should *never* pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from you trying to share `this.promised` across `update()` and the async behaviour inside `parseItem()`.

To fix this, you can instead return a `Promise` from `parseItem()` that represents every `Promise` created inside.

For example, a simplified version of this:

```
async parseItem(relation) {
  const result = await ask(relation);
  return await Promise.all(result.map(i => {
    const relations = i.relations;
    return Promise.all(relations.map(parseItem));
  }));
}
```

As you can see, inside `parseItem()` we're waiting for everything to recurse before resolving the `Promise`.

To apply this to your code, it might look something like this:

```
async parseItem(relation) {
  if (relation.wasResolved === true) {
    return true;
  }

  console.log('Parsing ' + relation.displaytitle);

  const result = await this.MediaWiki.ask('[[Has source element::' + relation.fulltext + ']]|?Has target element');

  const nestedPromises = result.map(el => {
    const targetElements = el.printouts['Has target element'];

    // This returns an array of an array of promises
    return targetElements
      .map(tel => this.getIndex(tel))
      .filter(index => index !== -1)
      .map(index => {
        this.elementsInView[index].parent = relation;

        // This returns a promise
        return this.parseItem(this.elementsInView[index]);
      });
  });

  // Easy way to flatten array of arrays
  const promises = [].concat.apply([], nestedPromises);
  await Promise.all(promises);

  // Set wasResolved to true
  relation.wasResolved = true;

  return true;
}
```

I can't guarantee this will work, though. It depends on the nature of this data structure and what effect it has to modify it whilst resolving all of these promises.

The main issue that raises questions is this line:

```
this.elementsInView[index].parent = relation;
```

What effect does this have on `parseItem`? And as a result of this mutation, I'd now be concerned whether or not multiple items passed to `parseItem` by `update` that are running in an interleaving manner might be simultaneously modifying data that they depend on.

At least in terms of the original question, this method should assist you in waiting for all promises to finish.